# How do I remove jQuery with the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My question is very simple, but I could not. JSON has a data. I'm doing push with loop somewhere. But the same values ​​are added again. I want to solve this. There will be only one to remove names with the same value.

**Summary;**

```
thelist = [{"name": "test", "name": "test2", "name": "test"}]
```

I want to delete the same names. There will only be one.

**Console Example Image;**

[image]

**Example jQuery Code;**

```
     var $el = this;
     var groupedItem = _.groupBy(itemList, function(t) { return t.unitPriceCurrency });

    $.each(groupedItem, function( key, value ) {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(value);
        var stringify = JSON.parse(obj);
        var amount = 0;
        var tax = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
            amount += stringify[i]['unitPrice'] * stringify[i]['quantity'];
            tax += stringify[i]['unitPrice'] * stringify[i]['quantity'] * stringify[i]['taxRate'] / 100;
        }

        var totalAmount = Math.round(amount * 100) / 100;
        var withTaxTotal = totalAmount + tax;

        for(let i = 0; i < totalLayout.length; i++) {                                
            totalLayout =  $.grep(totalLayout, function(value) {
                return totalLayout[i]["name"] != value.name;
            });
        }

        totalLayout.push(
            {"name": key + ' Amount'},
            {"name": key + ' Tax'},
            {"name": key + ' Total Amount'}
        );

        $el.model.set(key + ' Amount', totalAmount);
        $el.model.set(key + ' Tax', Math.round(tax * 100) / 100);
        $el.model.set(key + ' Total Amount', withTaxTotal);
    });
```

Comment: Your image is broken. I assume it's working for you, but for external requests we get a 403 Forbidden error. Even without the image the question should have enough detail to understand what you're asking and diagnose the issue, which is currently not the case

Comment: I'm guessing English isn't your first language, but the question as written is very hard to understand. An example of what is going wrong, and what you want as output, would help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry. My English is bad. You see the picture again? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I added summary. @MikeBrockington

Comment: So you want to reduce your list to only unique values? And can't do it at source?

Comment: Yes, none of them will be the same. They must all be Unique. @MikeBrockington

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a try using `filter` and `findIndex`

```js
  thelist = [{"name": "test"}, {"name": "test2"}, {"name": "test"}]

  Array.prototype.distinctBy= function(key){
     return this.filter((value, index, self)=> {
      return self.findIndex((v, i)=> v[key] === value[key]) === index
     });
  
  }

  console.log(thelist.distinctBy("name"))
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image the object should look like this

```
thelist = [{"name": "test"}, {"name": "test2"}, {"name": "test"}]
```

and you can use filter to achieve your desired result

```
thelist = thelist.filter(
            (item, index, self) =>
                index ===
                self.findIndex(t =>
                    Object.keys(thelist[0]).every(prop => t[prop] === item[prop])
                )
        );
```

Comment: No, not working. This is what should be.
thelist = [{"name": "test"}, {"name": "test2"}]

Comment: @Dodiş are you sure?.. the only thing i missed maybe is assigning the result to **theList** and im getting the result in console